# Do Ruby Resque workers run in parallel?

Tags: ruby, resque

I queued up a bunch of jobs given each one an id that gets printed out. What I find surprising is when I queue up 140 jobs each with varying sleep(n) in them I still see the output of the workers in sequential order. Here is some example output of pulling down pages from an external http api:

Page: 124
Page: 125
Page: 126
Page: 127
Page: 128
Page: 129
Page: 130
Page: 131
Page: 132
Page: 133

Shouldn't this come back out of order since each page could take different amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each resque worker runs in a single thread. If you only have one resque worker processing a given queue, that queue will be processed serially. If multiple resque workers process a single queue you should see the results come back out of order as you expected.

Comment: Side-note: I find the resque-pool gem makes it much easier than the out-of-the-box Resque rake tasks to manage multiple queues with multiple workers each.